# Why value at operator(*) not work when the pointer is pointing to an array?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

I have the following two code snippets to copy an array into another array in C written VS Code :

Snippet 1 ~

```
int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int arr_copy[5];
int *ptr = arr;
for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
{
    arr_copy[i]=*ptr[i];
}
```

Snippet 2~

```
    int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int arr_copy[5];
    int *ptr=arr;
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        arr_copy[i]=ptr[i];
    }
```

The first snippet throws an error on compilation saying *ptr[i] is invalid but the second snippet works. Shouldn't the first one return the value stored at pointer ptr[i] whereas second one should return the integer address of ptr[i]? Is it just the way C syntax is written or is there some logic behind it?

Comment: Because `*ptr[i]` is the same as `*(ptr[i])`. In fact, since for any pointer or array `ptr` and index `i`, the expression `ptr[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(ptr + i)`, the dereference is built into the array indexing. So `*ptr[i]` would be `*(*(ptr + i))`, which is one dereference too many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s go through this step by step.

1. `ptr` is a pointer to the first element of `arr`.
2. `ptr[i]` is equivalent to `*(ptr+i)`, or in this case `arr[i]`.

   - You see, there is an implicit dereferencing operation behind the scenes.
3. `*ptr[i]` would attempt to reference the *integer value* stored in the array, that is, to read memory from a somewhat arbitrary position. This will fail almost always.

Comment: `*ptr[i] would attempt to reference the integer value` - no it syntax error as you cannot dereference the integer value before converting it to the pointer type for example: `*(int *)ptr[i]`

Comment: Yeah, I wasn’t clear enough, but that was what I tried to mean by "attempt".